# Dismissing modal paper-dialog fails remove opaque backdrop

Tags: polymer, paper-elements, polymer-2.x

When my modal `paper-dialog` is attached to `my-app.html`, dismissing it fails to clear the opaque backdrop. But when the dialog is attached to a page in `my-app.html`, the backdrop is removed on dismissal.

I have a modal `paper-dialog` that I want to share among many pages so I place it in `my-app`. I've placed in `my-app` so:

```
<iron-pages role="main" selected="[[routeData.page]]" 
    attr-for-selected="name" selected-attribute="visible" 
    fallback-selection="404">
  <my-login name="" route="[[subroute]]"></my-login>
  <my-todos name="my-todos" route="[[subroute]]"></my-todos>
  ...
  <my-404-warning name="404"></my-404-warning>
</iron-pages>

<paper-dialog id="errorDlog" modal>
  <h2>Error</h2>
  <p>[[o_error]]</p>
  <div class="buttons">
    <paper-button dialog-confirm autofocus>Close</paper-button>
  </div>
</paper-dialog>
```

To show the dialog using a custom event triggered from any of my pages, I follow Polymer's instructions to bind my listener to the window (see ["Add and remove listeners imperatively"](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/events#imperative-listeners). Using this technique, I open the dialog from `my-login` with `window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('o_error', {detail: 'login error'}));`. But when dialog is dimissed, the backdrop remains opaque.

However, if I add an `id` to `my-login` and in `ready()` call `this.$.loginForm.addEventListener('o_error', e => this._errorListener(e));`, I open the dialog from `my-login` with `this.dispatchEvent(...`). Now dismissing the dialog does clear the opaque backdrop.

So, I have a workaround, but I don't think I should have to `addEventListener()` to every page.

Comment: maybe you could create a jsbin or something like that... it's really hard to follow how you try to do it if you can't see the "real" code...

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to, but maddeningly my small sample is working. I started with a copy and paste of the modal parts and launching it from a page within a page. That worked so I've have been adding more to see what breaks it--`<app-header`, `<app-location>`, etc. but it still works. Maybe as I add more--polymer-redux, Node.js, etc--I can break it. Till then I've a cheaper workaround with a custom event that sets `iron-overlay-backdrop`'s `opened` property to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the error, and the solution. First, I am using Node.js and Express, and (mostly) following [Wendy Ginsberg's recommendation](https://wmginsberg.github.io/blog/poly-express) on structure. It *appears* that the server route

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile("index.html", {root: '.'});
});
```

fires twice--once for the missing page, and once for the 404 route itself. The `iron-overlay-backdrop` is overwritten and the lost `iron-overlay-backdrop` *appears* to be what the dialog is trying to close. (Note, I say "*appears*" because I can't see this come and go in DevTools. I'm guessing based on the effect).

My solution has been to create an `<error-dialog>` element containing my `<paper-dialog>` and the `EventListener`, and place `<error-dialog>` in `index.html`:

```
<body>
  <my-app></my-app>
  <error-dialog></error-dialog>
  <noscript>
    Please enable JavaScript to view this website.
  </noscript>
</body>
```

Now I can show this dialog from anywhere in my application with

```
let msg = ...
const dlog = document.querySelector('error-dialog');
dlog.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('o_error', {detail: msg, bubbles: true, composed: true}));
```

Overall I like Node.js, but it presents some challenges. For example, do not `lazy-load` your Polymer 404 page if you're using Node.js & Express: The Node.js console will show a 200 status for the nonexistent page, and an empty `<div>` where your 404 message should be.

Answer (score 0):

```html
if (active) {
    this.listenToOverlayChanges();
 } else {
    this.unlistenOverlayChanges();
 }
```